# I need to use Appium 2 for CodeceptJS mobile tests

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, codeceptjs, codecept

Because latest iOS is making problems with Appium 1.x, Appium team is no longer supporting it,
and Appium 2 is working ok - I need to use v2...

CodeceptJS 3.3.x is using Appium 1.x now and because of the '/wd/path' used by default in CodeceptJS Appium helper, I can't set it to use Appium 2.
When starting a test, CodeceptJS fails with:

```
Error: Failed to create session.
The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

Please make sure Selenium Server is running and accessible
Error: Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Failed to create session.
The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

Please make sure Selenium Server is running and accessible
```

And Appium 2 fails with:

```
[debug] [HTTP] No route found for /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 404 1 ms - 211
```

Is there a way to change the default '/wd/path' to just '/' ?
Or is there another helper or something for Appium 2?

Part of the codecept.config.js file:

```
        Appium: {
            host: process.env.CLOUD_HOST || 'localhost',
            port: parseInt(process.env.CLOUD_PORT) || 4723,
            app: (PLATFORM_NAME === 'iOS') ? APP_PATH_IOS || 'com.mobile.beta' : APP_PATH_ANDROID,
            desiredCapabilities: {
                platformName: process.env.PLATFORM_NAME || 'iOS',
                platformVersion: process.env.PLATFORM_VERSION || '16.0',
                automationName: process.env.AUTOMATION_NAME || 'xcuitest',
                deviceName: process.env.DEVICE_NAME || 'iPhone Xs',
                appPackage: process.env.APP_PACKAGE,
                appActivity: process.env.APP_ACTIVITY,
                xcodeOrgId: process.env.XCODE_ORG_ID,
                // udid: process.env.UDID, // used only for real iOS device

            },
        },
```

=========================================

- **UPDATE:**

I started Appium with --base-path /wd/hub (appium --base-path /wd/hub) but now another error appears:

```
Error: Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Failed to create session.
All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: platformVersion,automationName,deviceName,appPackage,appActivity,xcodeOrgId,app

Please make sure Selenium Server is running and accessible
```

I tried updating the **capabilities** in *codecept.conf.js* with *appium:* prefix, but either I do it wrong or it doesn't work:

The Update:

```
        Appium: {
            host: process.env.CLOUD_HOST || 'localhost',
            port: parseInt(process.env.CLOUD_PORT) || 4723,
            app: (PLATFORM_NAME === 'iOS') ? APP_PATH_IOS || 'com.mobile.beta' : APP_PATH_ANDROID,
            desiredCapabilities: {
                'appium:platformName': process.env.PLATFORM_NAME || 'iOS',
                'appium:platformVersion': process.env.PLATFORM_VERSION || '16.0',
                'appium:automationName': process.env.AUTOMATION_NAME || 'xcuitest',
                'appium:deviceName': process.env.DEVICE_NAME || 'iPhone Xs',
                'appium:appPackage': process.env.APP_PACKAGE, // not needed for iOS
                'appium:appActivity': process.env.APP_ACTIVITY, // not needed for iOS
                'xcodeOrgId': process.env.XCODE_ORG_ID, // not needed for Android
                udid: process.env.UDID, // used only for real iOS device testing
            },
        },
```

Error:

```
Error: Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Invalid or unsupported WebDriver capabilities found ("platformVersion", "deviceName", "appPackage", "appActivity", "xcodeOrgId", "app", "tunnelIdentifier"). Ensure to only use valid W3C WebDriver capabilities (see https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#capabilities).If you run your tests on a remote vendor, like Sauce Labs or BrowserStack, make sure that you put them into vendor specific capabilities, e.g. "sauce:options" or "bstack:options". Please reach out to to your vendor support team if you have further questions.

Please make sure Selenium Server is running and accessible
```

Error#2:

```
Error: Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Invalid or unsupported WebDriver capabilities found ("deviceName", "app", "tunnelIdentifier"). Ensure to only use valid W3C WebDriver capabilities (see https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#capabilities).If you run your tests on a remote vendor, like Sauce Labs or BrowserStack, make sure that you put them into vendor specific capabilities, e.g. "sauce:options" or "bstack:options". Please reach out to to your vendor support team if you have further questions.

Please make sure Selenium Server is running and accessible
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting Appium server using the CLI you can use something like `appium -p 4726 --base-path /wd/hub` which will make it accept requests on the old endpoint

Update:
With Appium 2.0, the Appium server will enforce strict compability with the W3C WebDriver specification when it comes to Capabilities. They can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities). Anything else that you provide for Appium should have the `appium:` prefix (like `appium:platformVersion`, `appium:appPackage` and so on)

Comment: This solved half of the the problem... 
Now a new error appeared: 

`
Error: Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Failed to create session.
All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: **platformVersion,automationName,deviceName,appPackage,appActivity,xcodeOrgId,app**

Please make sure Selenium Server is running and accessible
`

Comment: I tried updating the capabilities in codecept.conf.js with appium: prefix, but either I do it wrong or it doesn't work:

The Update: _'appium:automationName': process.env.AUTOMATION_NAME,_

The Error:
_Error: Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Invalid or unsupported WebDriver capabilities found ("platformVersion", "deviceName", "appPackage", "appActivity", "xcodeOrgId", "app", "tunnelIdentifier")._

Comment: I updated the answer with more info on the capabilities

Comment: I know, I updated them, and posted the new error in the **UPDATE:** section.

Looks like CodeceptJS's Appium helper doesn't support the strings with prefix: 'appium:automationName': process.env.AUTOMATION_NAME

when I updated them like this, appium (console) didn't even noticed the coonection ...

Comment: You have updated only `automationName`. If you look closely it is listed in your first error and it is no longer listed in your second error. You also need to update `"platformVersion", "deviceName", "appPackage", "appActivity", "xcodeOrgId", "app", "tunnelIdentifier"` to use the prefix

Comment: I changed them all, I just posted one as an example

Comment: The thing with the error is that it's for Webdriver and it says:  

**Error: Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Invalid or unsupported WebDriver capabilities found**

Comment: Yes, it is with WebDriver because you keep providing it incompatible capabilities. This looks like incompatibility of CodeceptJS with Appium 2.0. You can move `app` inside `desiredCapabilities` but you will keep getting an error due to `tunnelIdentifier` because if you are not setting it, then it is being hardcoded somewhere in CodeceptJS code

Comment: If I move app to desiredCapabilities (with or without 'appium:'), it throws this error:     
**Could not load helper Appium from module './helper/Appium':

        Appium requires either platform and app or a browser to be set.
        Check your codeceptjs config file to ensure these are set properly
          {
            "helpers": {
              "Appium": {
                "app": "/path/to/app/package"
                "platform": "MOBILE_OS",
              }
            }
          }**

Comment: You will probably have to raise an issue with CodeceptJS maintainers to ask for support of Appium 2 or at least some pointers how to change the code to get it to work(if at all possible atm)

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a problem with the CodeceptJS's Appium helper and needs to be updated to follow the Appium's more strict compability with the W3C WebDriver specification.

The update needs a support for prefixes like:

```
...
appium:platformName: 'iOS'
appium:automationName: 'xcuitest'
...
```

or

```
...
browserstack:platformName: 'Android'
saucelabs:automationName: 'uiautomator2'
...
```

for now, we can't configure variables with prefixes.

There's also no way I know of, to contact the CodeceptJS maintainers for making this update.

Answer (score 0):

On my side I commented these 3 lines in the Appium.js file
and now it runs

```
//config.capabilities.deviceName = config.device || config.capabilities.deviceName;
config.capabilities.browserName = config.browser || config.capabilities.browserName;
//config.capabilities.app = config.app || config.capabilities.app;
config.capabilities.platformName = config.platform || config.capabilities.platformName;
//config.capabilities.tunnelIdentifier = config.tunnelIdentifier || config.capabilities.tunnelIdentifier;
config.waitForTimeoutInSeconds = config.waitForTimeout / 1000;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).